# Do dolphins help humans to the surface?

Tags: dolphins

There are many [stories](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmLYGzlPLj0&feature=youtu.be) of drowning humans being rescued by Dolphins. Are these just tales or does this actually occur?

Comment: [Here is a case](http://archives.cnn.com/2000/WORLD/europe/08/29/italy.dolphin.reut/).

Comment: have no idea if they rescue humans when drowning but i know that there are documented cases of them raping people! (as a side-note)

Comment: What sort of answer will you find acceptable if you are not willing to accept news stories?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: It's just a boy. Are there documented examples with more reliable witnesses?

Comment: @Xitcod13 please provide that documentation in the form of an answer to [This Question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10625/do-dolphins-rape-humans)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this](http://repository-intralibrary.leedsmet.ac.uk/open_virtual_file_path/i391n142863t%20/Animal%20Rescuers.pdf) in the *International Journal of Aquatic Research and
Education*

> The use of dolphins in rescuing humans has been instinctive, rather
>   than the result of formal training. Dolphins have rescued drowning
>   victims or abandoned survivors by allowing them to ride on their back
>   (Betancourt, 1998; Catton, 1990) or by psychologically encouraging
>   them with their presence to continue their efforts to reach the shore
>   (Waga News, 2001).

The paper cites many evidence of dolphins helping drowning human (which can be found in the references a the end of the paper). However, the study also claims that animals can either do it by training or by instinct (depending on the breeds).

> Therefore it seems that animals can rescue humans either by instinct
>   or by being trained for rescue.

Other papers can be found supporting the evidence of dolphins having helped drowning humans through history:

[Drowning in Ancient Greek history and mythology](http://repository-intralibrary.leedsmet.ac.uk/open_virtual_file_path/i391n190404t/Drowning%20in%20Ancient%20Greek%20History%20and%20Mythology.pdf)

[Drowning incident rescuer characteristics: Encoding the first component of the 4W model](http://repository-intralibrary.leedsmet.ac.uk/open_virtual_file_path/i1955n237905t/Drowning%20Incident%20Rescuer%20Characteristics.pdf)

**And books:**

[Inside the Mind of a Clever Dolphin](http://books.google.ca/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=7gvcXTP_4oQC&oi=fnd&pg=PA4&dq=dolphin%20save%20drowning&ots=9hwmIY63NU&sig=sOVPD6LARA68nyXC8ZNKCwqZl_w#v=onepage&q=dolphin%20save%20drowning&f=false)

[Swimming with Dolphins](http://books.google.ca/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=KHRfuZdxfLEC&oi=fnd&pg=PA4&dq=dolphin%20save%20drowning&ots=JgydLbh520&sig=mTHV1SKG6sFAShiHaaDDO4Dcj-s#v=onepage&q=dolphin%20save%20drowning&f=false)

An important side note should be expressed. Evidence of dolphins helping drowning humans does not mean that dolphins **would** save a human in case of drowning. There are also some evidences of them [attacking human](http://www.aquaticmammalsjournal.org/share/AquaticMammalsIssueArchives/1995/AquaticMammals_21-02/21-02_Dudzinski.pdf) or [letting them drown](http://books.google.ca/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=AqNiTC3uqGAC&oi=fnd&pg=PA71&dq=dolphin%20save%20drowning&ots=ctl-KlxAPC&sig=z6pn0EMI_8e5FviHHMyHPPk_oNg#v=onepage&q=dolphin%20save%20drowning&f=false).

Comment: There are also a large number of reports from news network around the world that can be found on Google.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to a book about Dolphins [The dolphin in history](http://archive.org/details/dolphininhistory00mont) *papers delivered by Ashley Montagu and John C. Lilly at a symposium at the Clark Library, 13 October 1962.
Published 1963 by William Andrews Clark Memorial Library, University of California in Los Angeles .*

A portion of the text read,

> Is there any evidence that dolphins save drowning swimmers ?  There
>   is.
>
> In 1945 the wife of a well-known trial attorney residing in  Florida
>   was saved from drowning by a dolphin.' This woman  had stepped into a
>   sea with a strong undertow and was immedi-  ately dragged under.

The same book is available [here](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/ia/dolphininhistory00mont) as well.

Hope this helps.